# hook_menu parameter can contain a forward slash

Tags: 7, hooks, routes

I've built a custom module to get cloudinary images and it works great. However, a bug has cropped up. You can navigate to /cloudinary/resource/public_id and it gets the image with public_id. On cloudinary there is now the ability to specify folders, so a public id could be something like "unitedstates/public_id". This is wrecking my hook_menu:

```
function cloudinary_menu() {    

    ...    

    $items['cloudinary/resource/%'] = array(
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'page callback'  => 'get_resource',
        'page arguments' => array(2)
    );
...
```

Is there any way to specify that anything after /% should be passed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so, but you can kludge something together pretty easily:

```
function get_resource() {
  $resource_path = implode('/', func_get_args()); 
}
```

Results:

- cloudinary/resource/unitedstates/public_id => unitedstates/public_id
- cloudinary/resource/unitedstates/foo/bar/public_id => unitedstates/foo/bar/public_id

And so on

Answer (score 2):

Additional arguments are still sent to page callback functions.

You might try doing a check for additional arguments:

```
function get_resource($id) {
  $args = func_get_args();
  if (count($args) > 1) {
    $id = end($args);
  }
  /** rest of your code **/
}
```

This way if the public id was "unitedstates/public_id", func_get_args() would return two items, the second one being "public_id" which would be set as the $id if there is more than one argument. Note this will always set the last argument as $id if there is more than one.

Comment: Nice one. I used func_get_args()